# Meaning of tA tC and tP

Tags: mysql, sql

If this is a duplicate I apologize, but looking for two-letter strings is quite hard in any search.

I'm looking for the meaning of `tA` `tC` and `tP` in the context of a MySQL query. And in the spirit of "teaching a man how to fish" it would be great if you could point me in the right direction of where to find this info in the future.

**Edit: The Query**

```
$wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("SELECT tA.* FROM ".AMYLITE_ADS." tA,
    ".AMYLITE_ADS_CAMPAIGNS." tC, ".AMYLITE_PACKAGES." tP
    WHERE tA.id=tC.ad_id AND tC.campaign_id=tP.campaign_id AND tP.zone_id=%d
    AND tP.date_end>CURDATE()
    GROUP BY tA.id ORDER BY RAND()", $zone->id));
```

Comment: Sounds like aliases to me. Need to see the query for a sensible answer. They are meaningless unless you created them.

Comment: So should I delete this question since it has been voted down to -2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected, they are table aliases

ie: in

```
SELECT tA.* FROM ".AMYLITE_ADS." tA
```

`tA` is a name given to the table name contained in `AMYLITE_ADS`

Answer (score 1):

They're table aliases. The constants you're referring to in your query is setting them.

Comment: It does't look like the constant is setting it:

`define('AMYLITE_ZONES',$wpdb->prefix. "amylite_zones");`

Comment: If you extracted the SQL statement from the `prepare` call into a separate string `sql = "..."`, then you could print the string and see that the two-letter names appear after a table name and specify an alias that is used throughout the rest of the query.  You'd pass the string variable to the `prepare` function afterwards, of course. Using table aliases means that most of the query doesn't change even when the table names do change (and aliases often shorten the query dramatically, making it much more readable).